# How to make the less common word of the query required in solr

Tags: solr

is there a way to make the less common word of a query required?

some way to convert directly in solr:
"Lucene in Action, Second Edition" to "+Lucene in Action, Second Edition"
or
"Apache Solr Essentials" to "Apache +Solr Essentials" Supposing that solr is a less common word in the index than essentials.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in multiple queries; first one query per word, which will give you a number of results, which will indicate how common each word is. After that you reformulate your final query accordingly. You could keep the word popularity in a cache to minimize the number of queries.

I realize you are probably trying to do this with one query - I can't think of any Solr functionality that would accomplish exactly that. Documents that contain the rarer words will already get higher scores than documents that contain the more common words, but you want something "stronger".